# All notifications have stopped

Tags: samsung

All notifications have ceased except for text messages and one shopping app. No audible notification, no notification symbol on my status bar at top of phone.How do I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: What Samsung model do you have, and which Android version? Did you recently installed an app?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the notifications page in settings and check if everything is set to on.